# Supabase realtime console log is not synced with presence event sync

Tags: javascript, reactjs, supabase, supabase-database

I am broadcasting my players positions.

```
// Subscribe registers client with the server
this.channel.subscribe(async (status: any) => {
  if (status === 'SUBSCRIBED') {
    const status = await this.channel.track({
      online_at: new Date().toISOString(),
      user_id: this.userId
    })
    // broadcasting player positions
    setInterval(() => {
      const player = this.player
      if (player) {
        const key = player.anims.currentAnim?.key;
        const velocityX = player.body.velocity.x;
        const velocityY = player.body.velocity.y;
        const positionX = player.x;
        const positionY = player.y;
        this.channel.send({
          type: 'broadcast',
          event: 'player-pos',
          payload: { 
            velocityX: velocityX, 
            velocityY: velocityY,
            positionX: positionX,
            positionY: positionY, 
            key: key 
          },
        })
      }
    }, 100)
  }
})
```

My channel listens for the broadcast and saves those positions with a javascript new Map()

```
  .on('broadcast', { event: 'player-pos' }, (payload: any) => {
        this.playerMap.forEach((obj => {
          if (this.userId !== obj.user_id) {
            // Create player sprite and add physics
            this.otherPlayer?.setVelocity(payload.payload.velocityX, payload.payload.velocityY) 
            if (payload.payload.key) {
              this.otherPlayer?.play(payload.payload.key, true)
            }
            if (obj.user_id && payload.payload.positionX && payload.payload.positionY) {
              this.playerMap.get(obj.user_id).positionX = payload.payload.positionX
              this.playerMap.get(obj.user_id).positionY = payload.payload.positionY
            }
          }
        }))
      })
```

On the presence sync event, I console log the positions in my Map.

```
  .on('presence', { event: 'sync' }, async () => {
    const usersObj = await this.channel.presenceState()
    for (const userId in usersObj) {
      if (!this.playerMap.has(userId)) {
        this.playerMap.set(userId, usersObj[userId][0])
      }
    }
    console.log('Sync playerMap', this.playerMap, 'totalPlayers', this.totalPlayers, 'playerMap.size', this.playerMap.size)
    this.playerMap.forEach((obj => {
      // need this.totalPlayers < this.playerMap.size check because presence runs at least twice
      // and second connection will create duplicate other player
      if (this.userId !== obj.user_id && this.totalPlayers < this.playerMap.size) {
        // Create player sprite and add physics
        const otherPlayerObj = this.playerMap.get(obj.user_id)
        console.log('otherPlayerObj', otherPlayerObj, 'otherPlayerObj.positionX', otherPlayerObj.positionX)
        this.totalPlayers++
        this.otherPlayer = new Player(
          this,
          otherPlayerObj.positionX,
          otherPlayerObj.positionY,
          'up'
        );
      }
    }))
  })
```

I open two clients.

My first client loads first.

I open a new window and open my second client.

When my second player connects, I can see the positions of my first client in the map and console log them fine.

[image]

I then look back at my first client that console logs the positions of my second client

[image]

I can see that otherPlayerObj.positionX exists. But I do not know why I am getting undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you inspect the websocket messages to make sure you're getting the sync message on both clients?

You can use [Chrome's inspector](https://umaar.com/dev-tips/193-websocket-viewer/) or the [Realtime Inspector](https://realtime.supabase.com/inspector/new) to help debug Realtime Channel messages.

Comment: I solved the problem by using the join event instead of sync and there weren't any issues. Forgot to close my question.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34353138)